# Code splitting - splitting single reducer

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm trying to implement code splitting based on routes. I saw examples where they use `injectReducers` method, but this approach is only useful when we want to introduce completely new reducer.

I would like to be able to split reducer actions per route. For example, I have top level `currentUser` reducer, which handles certain actions. When I enter `/login` route, I would like to update `currentUser` reducer and add an ability to handle some new actions specific for `/login`.

Do you have any idea how to handle this properly?

Answer (score 0):

You could change your top-level reducer to a call to `combineReducers`, which would combine the `currentUser` reducer with another reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

const currentUser = (state, action) => { ... }
const loginReducer = (state, action) => { ... }

export default combineReducers({
  currentUser,
  login: loginReducer,
})
```

The state resulting from this reducer would then look like the following:

```
{
  currentUser: {
    ...
  },
  login: {
    ...
  }
}
```

You could also assign `currentUser` as a call to `combineReducers`, splitting it into pieces:

```
const login = (state, action) => { ... }
const info = (state, action) => { ... }

const currentUser = combineReducers({
  login,
  info
})
```

which results in state like:

```
{
  currentUser: {
    login: { ... },
    info: { ... }
  }
}
```

Comment: @caspg: You can see more about this [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UsingCombineReducers.html).